# How to prove that the transpose operation maps an arbitrary qubit to its complex conjugate?

Tags: quantum-state, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

How to prove that the transpose operation maps an arbitrary qubit to its complex conjugate, $|\psi^*\rangle \rightarrow |\psi\rangle$

Comment: In case you're not aware if it: please note that the transpose is not a valid quantum map, as it is not completely positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about that projector
$$
\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|.
$$
Note that this is Hermitian, $\rho^\dagger=\rho$. Take the transpose,
$$
{\rho^\dagger}^T=\rho^T
$$
but since the hermitian conjugate is the complex conjugate transpose, ${\rho^\dagger}^T=\rho^\star$.

If you want to see what pure state $\rho^\star=|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$ corresponds to, think of $\rho$ as a matrix and find a non-zero column. That column is proportional to $|\psi\rangle$. The same column of $\rho^\star$ is proportional to $|\phi\rangle$. It should thus be clear that $|\phi\rangle=|\psi^\star\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

This question makes more sense in density matrix notation. You can then ask how to prove that
$$ (|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|)^T = |\psi^*\rangle\langle \psi^*|.$$
It's not difficult, just write the state in some basis, $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i |i\rangle$, and apply the operations.

Answer (score 0):

*I hope I understoody your question correctly but I think that there is nothing to prove, it is simply a definition.*

Lets have a quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ which is described by a column vector. Then quantum state $\langle \psi|$ is defined as $(|\psi\rangle^T)^*$, i.e. coefficients are complex conugate numbers and the column vector is transposed. In the end you, have row vector with complex conjugated coefficients.

Maybe, a thread [How does bra-ket notation work?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-does-bra-ket-notation-work) would be helful for getting deeper understanding.