# For two-qubit systems, do we have $\langle 01|01\rangle = \langle 0|0\rangle\langle 1|1\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, terminology-and-notation

I am new to quantum computing and I want to know the following: If I have a 2 qubit system in state e.g. $\left|01\right>$ and I want to calculate the probability of measuring e.g. $\left<01\right|$ I can write it as following: $|\left<01|01\right>|^2$. Now is the notation $\left<01|01\right>$ equal to this notation $\left<0|0\right>\left<1|1\right>$?

Comment: welcome to the site. Please note that it is strongly recommended to format math in posts using mathjax. See https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/55 for a brief rundown on how it works. It is also strongly encouraged to add as much context as possible regarding your question, including in particular what exactly you do not understand about the topic. See https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more info. Here for example, what do you know about how braket notation works? Does https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/91/55 answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In general, given two Hilbert space $H_1$ and $H_2$ with inner product $\langle \cdot |\cdot \rangle_1$ and  $\langle \cdot | \cdot \rangle_2$ then for $u_1, v_1 \in H_1$ and $u_2,v_2 \in H_2$ we have that

$$\langle u_1 \otimes u_2 | v_1 \otimes v_2 \rangle =  \langle u_1|v_1\rangle_1 \cdot \langle u_2|v_2\rangle_2$$

Answer (score 2):

A more general rule is called *the mixed-product property:*
$$
(A \otimes B) (C \otimes D) = AC \otimes BD,
$$
which holds for any matrices $A,B,C,D$ of such sizes that we can form the matrix products $AC$ and $BD$.